# How to run for loop asynchronously with inquirer prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var inquirer = require("inquirer");
var words = ["ALPHA","BRAVO","CHARLIE","DELTA","ECHO","FOXTROT","GOLF","HOTEL","INDIA","JULIET","KILO","LIMA","MIKE","NOVEMBER","OSCAR","PAPA","QUEBEC","ROMEO","SIERRA","TANGO","UNIFORM","VICTOR","WHISKEY","XRAY","YANKEE","ZULU"];

function nodeMan() {
  var wrongs = 0;
  var lettersGuessed = [];
  var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
  var goldenBoy = word.split("");
  var blank = "_" * word.length;

  console.log(blank);

  for (var i = 0; wrongs < 10; i++) {
    var neem = "Question " + i;
    inquirer.prompt([{name: neem, message: "Guess a letter"}]).then(function(response) {
      console.log("print");
      lettersGuessed.push(resposne.name);
      if (response.name.length < 1 && lettersGuessed.indexOf(response.name)) {
        console.log(" first if statement cleared");
        for (var u = 0; u < goldenBoy.length; u++) {
          if (goldenBoy[u] === response.name) {
            blank[u] = response.name;
            console.log(blank);
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
nodeMan();
```

Trying to run this asynchronously. As of rn I get an infinite loop of "Guess a letter" prompts. Need help getting inquirer to shoot one question at a time instead of infinitely. Thanks for your time!

to set up a test folder don't forget to npm init and inquirer

Comment: Not going to happen with a loop. You are going to have to create your own loop by calling the function for the next iteration.

Comment: Your code is awful. Just look at the pyramid of tabs. Anytime you see an indentation of more than ~3 levels, it's automatically bad code and you should consider rewriting it.

Comment: @epascarello you can if you use `async/await`

Comment: That assumes that the 3rd party library supports promises (too lazy to look), else you are basically just writing promises. Personally this code does not need anything complicated when a simple callback can do the job.

Comment: `var blank = "_" * word.length;` - no, not in javascript

Comment: also, `wrongs` is always `0` - so, always `< 10` - you have an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `for` loop and need to use a recursion: inside the response to your question, you need to decide if you are going to ask another question and fire up that same question again (from within your callback).

Here is a basic code structure to get you going:

```
function nodeMan() 
  let wrong = 0; // Store the number of wrong answers
  const askQuestion = () => {
    inquirer.prompt([{name: neem, message: "Guess a letter"}]).then((response) => {
      // Here check the answer and decide if you want to ask another question
      // [...]
      wrong++;
      // As long as less than 10 wrong answers, ask the question again
      if (wrong < 10) {
        // Ask the next question
        askQuestion (); // Recursion !
      }
    }
  };        
  askQuestion();                                                                                                            
}
nodeMan();
```

Comment: You can use a for loop if use `async/await`

Comment: Correct, trying to keep it simple for now. OP didn't even use arrow functions

Comment: Just clarifying the comment *"can't use a for loop"* which would have been true not too long ago but isn't entirely accurate any more. Agree that probably better to use recursive approach for this anyway

Comment: How is askQuestion() executed the first time? It is only defined but never called in your code.

Comment: @leonheess I guess you can call it wherever you need it. In that case, further down the nodeMan function

Comment: @klugjo So it's intentional that the code in your answer doesn't do anything because the only thing happening in `nodeMan()` is constants being declared which are never used because they are scoped out of everything else?

Comment: Added the function call to start the recursion

Comment: If you also change the `wrong` from being a `const` to `let` it truly becomes a MWE (:

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to run your code under NodeJS 7.0+, you can declare a function as ["async"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function and then use ["await" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for waiting asynchronous response in for loop.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var inquirer = require("inquirer");
var words = ["ALPHA", "BRAVO", "CHARLIE", "DELTA", "ECHO", "FOXTROT", "GOLF", "HOTEL", "INDIA", "JULIET", "KILO", "LIMA", "MIKE", "NOVEMBER", "OSCAR", "PAPA", "QUEBEC", "ROMEO", "SIERRA", "TANGO", "UNIFORM", "VICTOR", "WHISKEY", "XRAY", "YANKEE", "ZULU"];

// declare an async function
async function nodeMan() {
    var wrongs = 0;
    var lettersGuessed = [];
    var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    var goldenBoy = word.split("");
    var blank = "_" + word.length;

    console.log(blank);

    for (var i = 0; wrongs < 10; i++) {
        var neem = "Question " + i;
        // wait for asynchronous response
        var response = await inquirer.prompt([{
            name: neem,
            message: "Guess a letter"
        }]);
        console.log(response)
        console.log("print");
        lettersGuessed.push(response.name);
        if (response.name.length < 1 && lettersGuessed.indexOf(response.name)) {
            console.log(" first if statement cleared");
            for (var u = 0; u < goldenBoy.length; u++) {
                if (goldenBoy[u] === response.name) {
                    blank[u] = response.name;
                    console.log(blank);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
nodeMan();
```